# switched my GEForce 1060 6GB to GEForce 1050Ti in ubuntu 20.4 LTS any driver to be installed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Switched my GEForce 1060 6GB graphics card to GEForce 1050Ti 4GB in ubuntu 20.4 LTS any driver to be installed? Given my GEForce 1060 6GB to my son as he plays games on computer and I just use the computer for regular stuff.
Do I need to make any changes in the graphics card driver?
In Windows the same nvidia drier worked without any issues.

Comment: Are you facing any difficulties? If there is any problem then edit your question and describe the problem. If there are no problems, then there is no question to ask. At least go to additional drivers and see which driver is currently in use, and add that information in your question. What makes you think that driver is not working with this card?

Comment: If you go out to this: Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers Both give this: Driver Version: 470.57 - Release Date: Mon Jul 19, 2021  If that is not the driver in Ubuntu, see if there is a newer one. But you must purge old driver before installing new or else major conflicts & issues. #What is installed
`dkms status`

Comment: The two cars should use the same driver but it's possible there are differences in configs.  If you aren't experiencing any problems you should be good to go with just swapping out the card. Obviously the 1050Ti will not perform as well as the 1060.